# Codeigniter usignd memcached

Tags: php, codeigniter, memcached

```
public function getAll(){ 
    if( !cache('PACKS')) { 
        $cached = ['packs' => $this->packs, 'v' => 1]; 
        cache('PACKS',$cached,60); 
    } 
    return cache('PACKS'); 
}
```

It is a codeigniter function which uses memcahced. It has two calling of cache('PACKS'), how can I refactor this use just one times, and give back te correct result always?

Comment: Assign it to a variable and it should be fine, you know the original value + the value you want to set in the if condition

Answer (score 0):

Here's an upgrade:

```
public function getAll(){ 
    $cached = cache('PACKS');

    if(!$cached) { 
        $cached = ['packs' => $this->packs, 'v' => 1]; 
        cache('PACKS',$cached,60); 
    } 
    return $cached;
}
```